# Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'boolean' in ANTLR4 JavaScript Lexer

Tags: javascript, node.js, antlr4, lexical-analysis, strong-typing

Node.js version:

```
jj5@orac:~/test/antlr4-js$ node --version
v5.10.1
```

Java version:

```
jj5@orac:~/test/antlr4-js$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

ANTLR4 version:

```
jj5@orac:~/test/antlr4-js$ java -jar ./antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar | head -n 1
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.5.3
```

My test script:

```
jj5@orac:~/test/antlr4-js$ cat run.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cd "`dirname $0`"
rm ECMAScript????* 2>/dev/null
export CLASSPATH=".:`pwd`/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar"
java -jar ./antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar -Dlanguage=JavaScript -visitor ECMAScript.g4
node antlr4/run.js
```

The error occurs on the last line `node antlr4/run.js` where Node.js runs [run.js](https://www.progclub.org/pcrepo/jj5-test/trunk/antlr4-js/antlr4/run.js):

```
jj5@orac:~/test/antlr4-js$ ./run.sh
[irrelevant warnings elided]
/home/jj5/repo/svn/pcrepo/jj5-test/antlr4-js/ECMAScriptLexer.js:881
    private boolean strictMode = true;
            ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jj5/repo/svn/pcrepo/jj5-test/antlr4-js/antlr4/run.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

So ANTLR4 seems to have generated some "strong typed" JavaScript and Node.js chokes on it. How can I resolve this issue..?

Note: if you have Node.js and Java installed you can reproduce like this:

```
cd /tmp
svn co https://www.progclub.org/svn/pcrepo/jj5-test/trunk/antlr4-js/
antlr4-js/run.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the ECMAScript.g4 grammar that I was using was designed for use in Java, not JavaScript. I created a new file to support JavaScript, you can get the details [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1166#issuecomment-207965998).